# Is R reflexive? symmetric? transtitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Define a relation on $\mathbb{Z}$ as $xRy$ if $|x-y| < 1$

Is $R$ reflexive? symmetric? transitive?

Okay so my reasoning is as such:

$|x-y| < 1$ only when $x=y$

$R$ exists if $x=y$

If $x=y$ the relationship is reflexive.

If $x=y$ the relationship is symmetric.

If $x=y$ the relationship is not transitive.

Counterexample of non-transitivity:

$(a,a) \wedge (b,b) \Rightarrow (a,b)$ is false.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Comment: Okay! Awesome thanks, I was wondering how to do that :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. I do agree with your claim that |x-y| < 1 iff x = y, so this relation is equivalent to equality. Therefore, I find it strange that you assert that this relation isn't transitive.

Comment: Is my counter example of non-transitivity not acceptable?

Comment: Transitivity holds if $aRb$ and $bRc$ implies $aRc$.  What does that imply about $a$, $b$, and $c$?

Comment: let:
a = a,

b = b,

c = b,

aRc is false

Comment: You need to relate $a$ to $b$ and $b$ to $c$, not $a$ to itself and $b$ to itself.

Comment: No, what you are writing it not transitivity. It should be: let $a = b$ and $b = c$; then we conclude that $a = c$. Do you not agree with that?

Comment: I agree that if a = b and b = c then a = c therefore transitive. Nevermind, I got it thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite. It is true that
$$
|x-y| < 1 
$$
if and only if
$$
x = y
$$
for integers.

So $R$ is actually equivalent to $=$, and hence is all three of reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.

For $xRx$, we note that $|x-x| = 0 < 1$. So $R$ is reflexive.

Also if $xRy$ then $x = y$, so $yRx$. So $R$ is symmetric.

Finally if $xRy$ and $yRz$ then $x = y$ and $y = z$, so $x = y = z$ and $xRz$. So this is transitive too.

Answer (score 0):

As you note if $x\neq y$ then $|x-y|$ is an integer greater than zero and hence $(x,y)\not\in R$

If $x=y$ then $|x-y|=0\in R$. So $R$ is the equality relation, which is know to be reflexive symmetric and transitive.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea about the relation in general - it is reflexive and symmetric given that equality is. However, it is also transitive - you seem to be taking transitivity as $(x,y)$ and $(z,w)$ being in $R$ implies that $(x,w)$ is as well - as in your last question, one must remove the middle element for transitivity, but it is necessary that the middle element be *the same*. So, this fails in the case of trying to use transitivity on $(a,a)$ and $(b,b)$ since we might see the middle elements as being $a$ and $b$ - and removing them gives $(a,b)$, but transitivity only would let us do that if $a$ and $b$ were the same (which they, in general, are not).

To be sure, we'd need something of the form $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ being in $R$, but not $(a,c)$ to break transitivity - and since, in this case, $a=b$ and $b=c$, as you show, it does follow that $a=c$ and hence that $(a,c)$ is in $R$.